# How can I display an image captured on a windows phone when using the Ionic Framework?

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, ionic-framework

I know Ionic Framework does not officially support Windows Phone, however I am 90% of the way there.

My issue is that when I take a picture the URI I get back is in the format:

```
///CapturedImagesCache/WP_20150710_007.jpg
```

However when I try and utilise this in an `<ion-slide-box>` which contains an `<img>`, I just get a white page icon in the top corner (iOS and Android work perfectly). The image is not displayed. Has anybody else managed to display a Windows Phone captured image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally worked out why I couldn't see the image. The URI given back was of the format: `///CapturedImagesCache/WP_20150710_007.jpg`

When I setup an alert on the `<img onerror="alert(this.src);">` I found that the src had the `unsafe:` prefix. I had the added the `imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist` to the controller module, however this was the wrong place, it is now in my main `app.js` before my `.run` section:

```
.config(function($compileProvider){
    $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|file|ms-appx|x-wmapp0):|data:image\//);
}
```

This regular expression allowed the `img.src` to have the path that was getting substituted.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using the Cordova Camera plugin, I would try using the base64-encoded image instead of linking to the file system.

```
Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
```

Also, if you're not already, I'd suggest trying out ngCordova: http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/camera/

From their example:

```
$cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
    image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
}, function(err) {
    // error callback
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I started the app using Base64 encoded data and it causes massive performance issues. I've eventually found the ideal solution for me, however I am sure your is correct as well.